# Le présent de l'indicatif se traduit-il par le « present perfect » en anglais ?

Tags: anglais, verbes, passé-composé

Learning French in Duolingo and I am learning prepositions.

I am having a problem with the following sentence.

> Elle est jolie depuis qu'elle est jeune

By this point, we haven't yet touched present perfect. Just present indicative. Naturally, therefore, I inputted the following translation

> She is pretty since she is young

In English, the above seemed so wrong. It should be "She has been pretty since she was young", which is of course correct grammatically.

My question is: does the present indicative in French also translates to present perfect in English? If yes, then when do we know when it translates to present indicative? If no, then is duolingo correct?

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking about at all but I'd like to point out that both sentences  "Elle est jolie despuis qu'elle est jeune" and "She's been pretty since she is young" sound really strange, not because of the grammar but because of the use of the word "jeune"/young. In French I'd have said sth like "elle a toujours été jolie" ou "elle est jolie depuis qu'elle est toute petite".

Comment: @Laure: cherche « depuis qu'elle est jeune » dans un moteur de recherche, et change d'avis. « Elle est jolie depuis qu'elle est jeune » c'est complètement français. Mais, il ne faut pas y réfléchir trop longtemps, parce que c'est illogique, et à force d'y réfléchir on finit par se demander ce que ça veut dire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Le fait que ça se dise ne me fera pas changer d'avis, je souligne que c'est illogique (pour dire comme toi) et donc que la phrase n'a pas beaucoup de sens quand on y réfléchis. Si je comprends bien tu es d'accord avec moi ?

Comment: Ok, alors on est d'accord :-)

Comment: Attention: "She's pretty since she is youg means"  "*Elle est jolie parce qu'elle est jeune*". "*Elle est jolie depuis qu'elle est jeune*" would translate: "she's been pretty since she was young."

Comment: When you write "By this point, we haven't yet touched present perfect." Wouldn't you mean "passé composé" instead of "present perfect"? If you don't, then I don't understand your question. "Present prefect" is an English tense, considered as one of the present tenses, "passé composé" is a French tense considered as one of the past tenses. So make sure in your question you're not using one term instead of the other.

Comment: I mean, we didn't tackle any past tenses before. That is why I am confused with the sentence.

Comment: OK. Then I think your sentence should be "By this point, we haven't yet touched past tenses. Just present indicative." And yes, present is correct in the French sentence. And yes your revised translation (after you'd given the answer) is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English present perfect being a present tense, the answer to your question is that often the *présent simple* will translate into the present perfect in English. The *présent simple* and the present perfect are both used to describe a present state of things and when present perfect is used with a time expression it will usually translate  into a présent simple.

*Je l'attends depuis deux heures*. I've been waiting for him since two.
*Je l'attends depuis une demie heure.* I've been waiting for half an hour.
*Elle est adorable depuis qu'elle est née.* She's been lovely since she was born.

**But:**

[I have read this book twice since my last birthday.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13127/2818)<sup>1</sup> *J'ai lu ce livre deux fois depuis mon dernier anniversaire.*
I've eaten the last piece of cake. *J'ai mangé le dernier morceau de gâteau*.

This is just a start and I expect there's a lot more to be said on the subject.

<sup>1</sup>:  Exemple pris sur [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hehe. Le premier exemple est complètement ambigu. Il faudrait écrire « Je l'attends depuis qu'il *est* deux heures » (même s'il n'est plus deux heures) pour indiquer que c'est un *since* et pas un *for*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: pas ambigu avec la traduction en anglais à côté. En fait j'ai fait exprès (habitude professionnelle) de prendre une phrase ambiguë quand on **n'a pas** la traduction. Et la phrase qui suis est aussi là exprès pur attirer l'attention sur l’ambiguïté. Parfois il faut éviter de trop mettre les points sur les **i** pour susciter la réflexion.

Comment: C'était surtout pour illustrer l'utilisation curieuse du présent dans la proposition introduite par *depuis*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: je pense que c'est justement cet emploi qui gêne le PO. Il devra réfléchir à la fois à l'usage de present perfect en anglais et de la différence en français entre le présent simple et le passé composé.