# Quelle traduction est correcte pour le temps « present perfect »?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, temps-grammatical

Quelle traduction pour la phrase ci-dessous est correcte?

> I have wanted to come to Montreal for so long and now I am in Montreal.

- Imparfait :

  > Je voulais venir à Montréal depuis si longtemps et maintenant je suis à Montréal.
- Conditionnel Passé :

  > J'aurais voulu venir à Montréal depuis si longtemps et maintenant je suis à Montréal.
- Passé composé :

  > J'ai voulu venir à Montréal depuis si longtemps et maintenant je suis à Montréal.
- Présent :

  > Je veux venir à Montréal depuis si longtemps et maintenant je suis à Montréal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Le présent de l'indicatif se traduit-il par le « present perfect » en anglais ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/le-pr%c3%a9sent-de-lindicatif-se-traduit-il-par-le-present-perfect-en-anglais)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans cette phrase « vouloir venir à Montréal » est un contexte, ce n'est pas le résultat d'une action. Le temps qu'il faut utiliser pour introduire un contexte passé c'est l'imparfait, comme dans ta première proposition :

> Je voulais venir à Montréal depuis si longtemps et maintenant je suis à Montréal.

Cela ne veut pas dire que tous les *present perfects* doivent être traduits par l'imparfait. Beaucoup seront traduits par un passé composé. Il n'y a pas de correspondance précise entre les temps en anglais et en français.